# How to get rid of blank line before table in r?

Tags: r

I have this line that creates table, but it creates it with empty line above data. Can I get rid of that empty line?

I was looking at `?table()`. Did not understand it.

```
table(WeightFramework$ievad, useNA = "ifany")
```

Expected result would be:

```
1 2
2 3
```

not

```
empty line
1 2
2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `dnn=NULL` to remove the empty line.

```
table(c(1,1,2,2,2), dnn=NULL)
#1 2 
#2 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

that line is a placeholder to write your column names.

Comment: I suspected it could be, but I do not need column names, so I dont want that empty line above my data.